# Is it possible for a Teensy 3.1 microcontroller to receive USB keyboard input?

Tags: avr, arm, keyboard, hid, teensy

[As I've read](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_keyboard.html), it is possible to have the teensy act as a keyboard for a computer.  I would like to know if the opposite is possible - can I collect keystrokes through the USB port on the teensy.  If this is not possible, can you explain why?

[image]

Comment: This forum post would suggest something along the lines of "not at this time." http://forum.pjrc.com/threads/26163-Are-there-examples-for-using-Teensy-3-1-as-a-USB-Host

Answer (score 3):

Technically, it is possible. The board already has a Micro-AB port, and the [MCU](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/datasheets.html) on it supports OTG. But all the examples now given are configuring it as a device. So you may need some coding to make it a host.

---

**Update:**

And, thanks to @PkP, he find their is a example for USB host in the MCU's [datasheet](https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/K20P64M72SF1RM.pdf), section 41.7.

Comment: See datasheet https://www.pjrc.com/teensy/K20P64M72SF1RM.pdf chapter 41.7 Host Mode Operation Examples. Seems fairly straightforward.